# Jboss 5 in Windows 7 Webservices issue

Tags: windows, web-services, jboss

I am using Jboss 5.0.1GA Jdk6 in windows 7 and while deploying my application which uses cxf webservices on server startup getting the following exception

STDErr:
. There is no @WebService annotation present in this method declaration. Please annotate it if you want expose with SOAP.

The application works fine on the dev unix server.

Any help would be appreciated

Regards,
Pradeep